# Execute LINQ generated SQL in SSMS

Tags: linq-to-sql, debugging

I use the LINQ DataContext's Log property to send the **generatated SQL** to the debug window. (There is a [post by Kris Vandermotten](http://blogs.u2u.be/kris/post/2007/03/14/Sending-the-LINQ-To-SQL-log-to-the-debugger-output-window.aspx) about that). That works fine, except that the ouputted SQL parameters are some SQL comments, and so I **can't run the query** in Management Studio. Here's an example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (@p0,@p1,@p2)
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [5]
-- @p1: Input Int (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
-- @p2: Input Int (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [13189086]
```

So, is there any tool that transforms this text into a valid SQL?

Comment: Is your desired result just the SQL statement with all the parameter placeholders substituted with their values? Or did you still want the `DECLARE` statements included, similar to the LINQPad output in my response?

Comment: It wolud be nice to have parameters DECLAREd, but it's reasonable with the parameters substituted. The goal is to have a query ehich can be Executed.

Answer (score 2):

You can grab [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net/) (free!) and run your LINQ to SQL directly. Then click on the "SQL" tab in LINQPad to see the generated SQL. It will `DECLARE` all the parameters for you and you could copy/paste that into SSMS (or click "Analyze SQL" from the SQL tab to launch it in SSMS). You can also run it directly from LINQPad.

Screenshot:

[image: LINQPad]

Comment: Thanks, it's a good entry, but not the answer i'm looking for.